# Python subprocess doesn't finish executing my script?

Tags: python, plotly, fastapi

I have a FastAPI route that runs a script from another directory. The script runs fine through the terminal with python, but doesn't finish executing when called from a subprocess through my route. I get the error: Command '['python', './scripts/get_map.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

```
@app.get('/getMap')
def get_map(): 
    try: 
        ...
        script_path = 'maps/get_map.py'
        subprocess.run(["python", script_path, json], capture_output=True, text=True, check=True) 
        
        return FileResponse('./images/us_guam_map.png')

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e: 
        return { "message": "Error", "error": str(e) }
```

This is my python script.

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context


import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_us_airport_traffic.csv')
df['text'] = df['airport'] + '' + df['city'] + ', ' + df['state'] + '' + 'Arrivals: ' + df['cnt'].astype(str)


fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(
        lon = df['long'],
        lat = df['lat'],
        text = df['text'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker_color = df['cnt'],
    ))
fig.update_layout(
        title = 'Most trafficked US airports<br>(Hover for airport names)',
        geo_scope='usa',
    )
fig.show()
fig.write_image('../images/map.png')     # saves as an svg file in /images 

...

# load geojson 
with open('../geojsons/guam.geojson') as f: 
    guam_geojson = json.load(f)


... generate another map and save it somewhere else for the route to retrieve 

usa_guam.save('../images/us_guam_map.png)
```

Why is this happening? Is there a better approach to running python code/script from a route/FastAPI?

I suspect that it has something to do with loading the geojson. The subprocess reaches fig.show() since it does display map.png. But even when I remove all the code after fig.write_image('../images/map.png'), I still get the same error.

Comment: Since you're using `capture_output=True`, why don't you print the captured error message? That should help understand why it's failing.

Comment: I see relative pathnames in the script you're calling.  It's probably being called with a current working directory other than what it expects, so those pathnames don't refer to the expected files.

Comment: @Barmar That helped me figure out the issue, thank you!

Comment: @jasonharper That worked! Can you explain why it's being called with a different working directory? What if I want to call the script from the terminal and the route? Is there a python way to get the correct path for either method?

Comment: @bestfirstsearch, working directory is inherited from your parent process. There's no such thing as a "correct" working directory -- it's a decision made by the calling process. If you want to generate paths relative to, say, the location of your source code (or detect that so you can perform an `os.chdir()` to make your working directory match it), we have Q&A already answered about how to do that; but it's your job to specify the behavior you want; we can't say what the "correct" thing is without a spec.

Comment: @bestfirstsearch, ...for something you're running as, say, a systemd service, you can also configure the working directory you want in the service configuration, not involving Python code in the decision at all.